# Align inline maths and text

Tags: alignment, inline

I would like to align my inline equations on the right of the text

```
\documentclass[12pt, A4]{article}

\begin{document}

Text: $a+b=c$

Longer Text: $x+y=z$ 

\end{document}
```

Which environment can I use to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE¨! Like this `\documentclass[12pt, A4]{article}
\begin{document}Text:           \hfill$a+b=c$\par
Longer Text:    \hfill$x+y=z$
\end{document}` ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am sorry, I meant aligning the equations along their left side, not along the right margin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `tabular` depending how long your text is, you could use `l` or `p` for your first column, I show both here

[image]

```
%\documentclass[12pt, A4]{article} article has no A4 option
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
   Text: & $a+b=c$\\
  Longer Text:& $x+y=z$
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushleft}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
   Text: & $a+b=c$\\
  Longer Text:& $x+y=z$ \\
  Much much much longer Text Text Text Text:& $w+x+y=z$ 
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}


\begin{flushleft}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedright}p{7cm}l}
   Text: & $a+b=c$\\
  Longer Text:& $x+y=z$ \\
  Much much much longer Text Text Text Text:& $w+x+y=z$ 
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be achieve this with `\makebox[length][l]{<text>} $<inline math>$` or its improved version `\eqmakebox[<label>][l]{<text>} ...` (the latter requires `eqparbox` package).

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\begin{document}
\eqmakebox[preeq][l]{Text:} $a+b=c$
\par\eqmakebox[preeq][l]{Longer text:} $x+y=z$
\end{document}
```

[image]